# How to call a dualHttpBinding(callback contract) from a webHttpBinding service in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, webhttpbinding, wsdualhttpbinding

Hi all I am facing one issue with dualHttpBinding and webHttpBinding in my application. Here is the overall scenario

I have a dotNet and Android application which consumes a WCF Service (which has three different bindings).

```
1. basicHttpBinding - For dotNet app (Service1.svc)
2. webHttpBinding - For Android to access via Rest full service (Service2.svc)
3. dualHttpBinding - For push notification to dotNet app(PushServie.svc)
```

When ever android app consumes a method in Servie2(AddOrderItems) - it inserts into database and in inturn shows a message in dotNet application (a push notification). For this I have used CallBackContract in PushService and it is working fine when I try to access the AddOrderItems method (in Servie2) from dotNet app (for testing purpose I did) and notification message is coming.

But my problem is how can I come to know whether and and when my AddOrderItems is being called from android app, so that I have to show a message (via CallBackContract) in dotNet app.

I tried to call PushServie.svc method(CallBackMessagge) from Servie2.svc after calling AddOrderItems method but no luck at all.

Here is the code for Service2 and PushService.svc,

```
    // AddOrderItems method in IService2 which is implemented in Servie2.svc
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddOrderItems", RequestFormat = 
    WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    bool AddOrderItems(RequestOrderItemData orderItemData);
```

and call back method in IPushService which is implemented in PushService.svc

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void DisplayMessage(int orderID, int tableID, string tableName);
```

Here is the code for DisplayMessage in PushService

```
 IPushNotificationCallBack Callback
    {
        get
        {
            return  
            OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPushNotificationCallBack>();
        }
    }
```

and the method in PushService.svc

```
public void DisplayMessage(int orderID, int tableID, string tableName)
{
   Callback.DisplayMessage(orderID, tableID, tableName);
}
```

I tried to search in googles and every one says that a webHttpBindin does not support a callback functionality.

My concern is I want to call my DisplayMessage method from AddOrderItems. If this can be possible with any modifications, I am really be in happy.

As far as I think I have posted all the necessary code, if some thing else requires, please let me know, I will post it.

Any help highly appreciated.

Warm Regards,
Ganesh

Comment: You'll need to either use `WsDualHttpBinding` (which may force you out of REST) or look at some sort of polling option.

Comment: As with my current scenario I must have both the services because my android app consumes through webHttpBinding and in return I need callback contract to be invoked which is from another service which has (dualHttpBinding).